# Implementing a solr.DateRangeField type in Sitecore

Tags: solr

We need to use DateRangeField query in Solr to perform two dates range filter.  Managed schema field sample:

```
<fieldType name="date_range" class="solr.DateRangeField"/>
```

I have written computed field to add two dates into dateTimeCollection and index to Solr as **dateRangeFilter_dtm** (computed field)

```
<field fieldName="dateRangeFilter" returnType="datetimeCollection" storageType="YES" indexType="datetimeCollection">
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Namespace xxxxxxxxxxxxx
 </field>
```

After indexing this computed field is getting added of type DatePointField (org.apache.solr.schema.DatePointField) in Solr. But we need to index this field of type DateRangeField to perform this query in Solr:

```
 ({!field f=dateRangeFilter_dtm op=Intersects}[2017-09-30T00:00:00Z TO 2020-10-25T23:59:59Z])
```

In order to perform this query, the field should be of DateRangeField type only. We tried using both Datetime Array and Datetime Collection returnType, but both are indexing as DatePointField fieldtype in Solr.

Is there an option in Sitecore to use or add DateRangeField typeMatch fieldmap?

Any help would be appreciated!!